# How do I handle not getting paid by an ex-employer for contract work?

Tags: salary, job-change, contractors

I worked for a small company for ~2 years. During that time, I made myself invaluable, etc. However, I eventually received an offer from another company that I decided to take. As a gesture of goodwill, when I put in my two weeks' notice at my old job, I offered to stay on doing contract work for them for as long as necessary.

I signed a contract where they agreed to pay me a certain rate (less than they would have paid any other contractor for the work I was doing). It was signed by both me and the CEO of the company.

One week after I started my new job, I worked x contracting hours. Week 2, I worked x hours again. They paid me for the 2 days of the month that I was still working for them at my previous salaried rate. However, they *did not pay me for my contracting hours*.

I sent an email at the end of the second week to do follow up. It was forwarded to the controller/accountant, who never responded. I emailed again, copying the controller, the supervisor, and the guy generally in charge of contractors with the same question, and never got a response. It's been another 2 weeks, and the normal pay date has come and gone without payment.

This is a fairly consequential amount of money. At this point, I do not intend to do any further work for them.

(Note: They've been taken to court for not paying contractors in the past, more than once.)

**Question:**

What is the best way to convince them to pay? I'd rather avoid any small claims court or anything.

**What I've decided to do:**

I'm going to create a formal paper invoice, email it to the controller, the guy in charge of contractors, the direct supervisor I was reporting to, and the CEO (who has his fingers in everyone's pot, which is part of the reason I left).

I'll be sending it to them from my personal email address instead of their company one. I'll also be sure to save any emails with regards to this somewhere besides on their computer to ensure I have any necessary evidence.

In addition, I'm going to print the invoice in a hard copy, with documentation  of the hours that I worked, as well as a copy of the contract with the part where they promised to pay me highlighted (or is that too passive aggressive?). I'll also send them the times where I requested clarification on when I would be paid.

Comment: Hello @phroureo welcome to The Workplace. I see too many questions in your post, could you please try to narrow them to a single (or 2 at most) questions? This will help you get better answers, as other  users will be able to understand better. Also, be careful as "Should I" questions or questions asking for *us* to make a choice for you are *off topic* in the site. I see you have valid questions, and other that could be reworded, could you give it a shot?

Comment: How are you reporting/tracking your hours?

Comment: @GrayCygnus Would this question border as a legal question?

Comment: @FrankFYC in a way, but IMO is written more as a workplace question. In one of the questions OP indicated that a solution that does not involve lawyers is preferable (That is why I consider all those questions should be narrowed down to fewer, more concise).

Comment: @GrayCygnus Understood. Don't think my answer involves lawyers unless OP really holds laptop hostage (in which a criminal defence lawyer might be needed).

Comment: Yes indeed, taking the laptop hostage is not recommended.

Comment: Have you sent them a formal written (paper) invoice?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I assumed it would be different because I had been a full time employee :/ In any case, I established my precedent that one instance of non-payment would end the relationship, so I'm only ~3 weeks * 6 hours in the hole.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That's what I decided I'm going to do. I'll send them a formal written invoice to each of the people involved in anything to do with money, with attached documentation of hours worked.

Comment: I should clarify: I established it internally, for myself (although I mentioned it to family and some of the other former employees of the company as well).

Comment: Glad you decided to formally invoice them. You have a formal, written contract with them.  They need documentation of the contract expenses. That contract work is for you, as an outside person, supplying services. Not sure why you thought they'd intermingle that with your employee compensation. They haven't paid you because you haven't billed them yet.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet There was an understanding that I would submit hours to them weekly, and they would pay me (like they do for interns and "part-time" employees).

Comment: Yes, and the way a contractor or outside company "submits hours" for pay is via a formal invoice.  Interns and part-time employees are still employees of the company.  You are a contract worker. Unless they are including benefits, this sounds like an independent contractor arrangement, which makes you not an employee. Since you probably haven't worked on this kind of a basis before, there's no reason for you to have known that. I was just stating that, from an accounting point of view, they can't disburse funds outside of the payroll system without a bill or invoice.

Comment: Can you be an employee + on an hourly contract basis?  Yes, but then (if it was the USA, for instance), they'd remove the normal payroll and income taxes before disbursing payment.  If they are paying you 100% of the agreed upon rate, then the assumption is that you report that income and send the government any payroll or income taxes due, yourself.  My assumption is that they were not planning on the logistical work of doing that on an employee basis, but wanted the simpler route of paying you the rate, which would also make you independent.

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory, I am not a lawyer.

> Do I hold the laptop "hostage" until they pay me?

First and foremost, don't attempt to blackmail a company, although you didn't say where you were located, I am sure in all corners of the world, this would be frowned upon, i.e. illegal.

> Alternatively, do I take the laptop back to them, apologize for not
>   being able to do any more contract labor for them, and ask them for
>   payment?
>
> 1) Do I ask for immediate payment when I take the computer in? Or
>   should I settle for a date and a promise?
>
> 2) Do I send an email first notifying them that I will no longer be
>   doing any contract labor? Or do I just show up on Monday morning with
>   the computer and say, in essence, "Sayonara suckers"?
>
> 3) Is there some tactful way that I can get my money from them that
>   doesn't involve courts/lawyers if they won't give me a date/check?

As for everything else, it will depend on your country where:

- The Contract was signed
- The Work Location
- The Judicial Jurisdiction of the above points.

At least in the US, there are two avenues (that are easy for you) to retrieve owned monies: small claims court, where you sue the employer directly; and filing a wage complaint with your state's dept. of labor.

In the former, send a demand letter detailing the signed contract, via certified letter. If they don't pay up, then file a lawsuit in small claims.

In the latter, you would have to go through the wage complaint as outlined by your local/state dept. of labor which varies by state and location.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I guess I won't keep their laptop until I'm paid. :P This is in the US, fwiw. Labor board might be interested to know that they don't pay contractors...

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT state anything saying that you are keeping the laptop. What you *can* say is that you expect a cheque for your contract work, and that you still have their laptop, and if they decide they don't want you to do more contract work, then a time needs to be arranged when they can pick up that laptop from your home.

Answer (score -1):

Don't take anything in, don't do any more work for them and if you're as invaluable as you think they will come looking for you. At which time present them with your bill once more and ignore anything that isn't a confirmation of payment.

This is the best strategy I have found. Just ignore them until they come to their senses. And then do not enter into any sort of negotiation or dialogue, just present your bill and ignore them again until it is paid.

Comment: The OP could be left ignoring them for a very long time if they have no intention of paying.

Comment: Oh, I know I'm worth nothing to them now. :P I decided as soon as I told them that I would contract that if they didn't pay me a single time that that would be the end of our working relationship.

Comment: @SimonB yes, that can happen, I would write it off to experience. But I wouldn't have given them a finished product without payment at this stage in my career. However it IS valuable experience which many freelancers go through and learn from. And it does usually come back to haunt them. However the OP at least has the laptop if they don't come back. If they do come back looking for it, just give the bill and ignore anything else.